# How to display multiple html pages in one layout in android webview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 1 layout which having 4 buttons for 4 HTML pages and another layout which have 1 webview.

How can I display 4 HTML pages in 1 webview or more using only one layout?

I tried to display only one HTML page. So I want only 1 layout which shows those HTML pages according to the user choice that clicked.

```
WebView htmlWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
    webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    htmlWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html");

        String htmlFilename = "new.html";
        AssetManager mgr = getBaseContext().getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream in = mgr.open(htmlFilename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
            String htmlContentInStringFormat = StreamToString(in);
            in.close();
            htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   public static String StreamToString(InputStream in) throws IOException 
   {
    if(in == null) 
     {
        return "";
    }
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
    }
    return writer.toString();

}
```

Comment: I saw that you get string from html file then display to webview. You can concat all html to one string and display. What is the matter here ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have one layout (and Activity I suppose) with the buttons that generate an action on the second Layout (and second Activity I suppose).
In this case, what about passing the parameter of the page choosen by clicking that specific button to the second Activity which contains the webview (and then showing the page passed as parameter)?